# Specifying the colours when using pcolor

Tags: matlab, graph

I am using the `pcolor` command to create images that display variability in sea surface temperatures. I am trying to set 0°C to be white, with warmer temperatures being shades of red and cooler temperatures being shades of blue. I am using the following command:

```matlab
pcolor(LON,LAT,squeeze(SSTAp(tt,:,:)));
shading flat
```

**Follow up**

```
white=[1 1 1];
yellow=[1 1 0];
orange=[1 0.5 0];
red=[1 0 0];
black=[0 0 0];
custom_map = [white; yellow; orange; red; black]; 
colorbar('YTickLabel',{'None','Moderate','Strong','Severe','Extreme'})
caxis([1,5]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a custom [`colormap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). The example below generates some data, plots it using `pcolor` and sets the colors according to your request.

```matlab
% Create data; a 50-by-50 matrix with a diagonal gradient
X = 1:50;
Y = X';
T = X+Y-30;

% Plot the data
pcolor(X, Y, T);
shading flat;

% Create colormaps
blues = [
    linspace(0, 1, 100); % red and green values are changing from 0 to 1
    linspace(0, 1, 100); % in order to create a blue-to-white transition
    linspace(1, 1, 100);
    ]';

reds = [
    linspace(1, 1, 100);
    linspace(1, 0, 100); % green and blue values are changing from 1 to 0
    linspace(1, 0, 100); % in order to create a white-to-red transition  
    ]';

custom_map = [blues; reds]; % this one is blues-white-white-red

colormap(custom_map);       % apply colormap to the figure
caxis([-50,50]);            % set color axis, this ensures that 0 is white
colorbar;                   % optional, show a colorbar
```

The above code produces this figure:
[image: Result]

Comment: Such a great response! Can I also ask, how can I add a title?

Comment: Check this guide: [Add Title and Axis Labels to Chart](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-title-axis-labels-and-legend-to-graph.html)

Comment: I have another colormap for a subplot. I have put the code for the second colormap in my original question. Running the script for both subplots displays the error 'dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent'. Is there a way to fix this?